# making gdb evaluate a multi-line or compound if statement all at once

Tags: debugging, gdb

Up until I started using Arch linux a couple of weeks ago, gdb would evaluate multi-line if statements atomically.  So for a condition like this:

```
39523   if ((RM != NULL) && 
39524       (RM->DefaultC != NULL) &&
39525       (MSched.RemapC != NULL) &&
39526       (RM->DefaultC->FType != mqftRouting) &&
39527       (RM->DefaultC != MSched.RemapC))
39528     {
...
...
39728     } /* END if ... */
39732   if (ClassFound != TRUE)
39733     {
```

The only thing I'd see in gdb (unless I explicitly did a list command) was the first line:

```
39523     if ((RM != NULL) && 
(gdb)
```

Now I'm seeing the following:

```
39523     if ((RM != NULL) && 
(gdb) 
39524         (RM->DefaultC != NULL) &&
(gdb) 
39523     if ((RM != NULL) && 
(gdb) 
39525         (MSched.RemapC != NULL) &&
(gdb) 
39523     if ((RM != NULL) && 
(gdb) 
39526         (RM->DefaultC->FType != mqftRouting) &&
(gdb) 
39523     if ((RM != NULL) && 
(gdb) 
39527         (RM->DefaultC != MSched.RemapC))
(gdb) 
39523     if ((RM != NULL) && 
(gdb) 
39732     if (ClassFound != TRUE)
```

I can see this kind of behavior being desirable, but I'd prefer to be able to configure it.  Does anyone know if this is possible?  I'm using gdb 6.7.1, built from source.  I was using this exact version, built from the same source, on my Ubuntu system before I switched to Arch.

Edit: I see the same behavior when using gdb --tui

gcc --version on my arch system:

```
gcc (GCC) 4.4.2
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

gcc --version on my ubuntu system:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 4.3.3-5ubuntu4) 4.3.3
Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: Your GDB output doesn't match your source. Could you please cut/paste *actual* GDB output. Also, this is likely related to the version of GCC you used, please identify what that is.

Comment: I'll do this at work tomorrow, I was out today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with gcc, not gdb.  gcc is emitting debug info for each line in the condition.  I'm not certain whether this change was intentional or whether it is a gcc bug.